# How to use preg_match properly PHP

Tags: php

I have got this if statement in my php code

```
$u = trim($u);

  $u = $con->real_escape_string($u);
  $u = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $u); 
  $u = str_replace("'", " ", $u );  
  $u =  str_replace('"', ' ', $u );
  $u=htmlspecialchars($u);
if(preg_match("/[^a-z_\-0-9\']/i", $u))
{
   echo "<b class='Usernametaken'>Please do not use any symbols</b>";
}
```

So it works for everything in between a-z,A-Z and 0-9,_,- but i also want it to work for apostrophe
For example if somebody's name is O'reily it will not accept it

Comment: And what is the problem now?

Comment: It is not working for  apostrophe @Rizier123

Comment: Add \ before apostrophe

Comment: But i have @TuhinSubhraMandal

Comment: @Khaleesi Works for me. Give us a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: Please give sample value for $u

Comment: O'reily @TuhinSubhraMandal

Comment: [norepro](https://regex101.com/r/lY2lE2/1)

Comment: It is the same as my code is it not? @Rizier123

Comment: It is the same code

Comment: @Rizier123 so why did u send me that link?:D

Comment: To show you that the code works.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself @Rizier123?

Comment: Yes, that is why I showed you your code in the link.

Comment: I dont mean in website @Rizier123

Comment: A question, you do know that your regex will return `0` on valid and `1` on invalid? Just checking, since it works for me as well.

Comment: In case no one noticed the edit: *"For example if somebody's name is O'reily it will **not** accept it"*, looks like the OP is looking to exclude `'` rather than include it in a name. Could you confirm that @Khaleesi?

Comment: No i want it to include it,but it won't

Comment: Worked for me also when i checked without any code.@MagnusEriksson

Comment: @Khaleesi Then don't state the opposite; Your question is is contradicting itself. Please edit your question and state you want to accept it.

Comment: Dude... `$u = str_replace("'", " ", $u ); ` - You're replacing the `'` with a space? No wonder it won't work. Your **actually** trying to match `O reily` instead of `O'reily`

Comment: I deleted it still nor working @MagnusEriksson

Comment: well... stop manipulating the string all together before matching. `$con->real_escape_string($u);` will probably mess it up as well. (it is escaping things like `'`)

Comment: @Khaleesi You are not matching spaces, therefore it will fail. If you are replacing quotes with spaces then just use `/[^a-z_\-0-9 ]/i` instead.

Comment: now mysql gives me an error :  Trying to get property of non-object @MagnusEriksson

Comment: You validate the string first, THEN you escape it (or better yet, use prepared statements). Nothing in the above code can give you that error message (if you just move the `$con->real_escape_string()` after the if). I think you got some code smell that we haven't seen.

Comment: I did as u told first i did all replace stuff then i checked then i escaped @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Again you need to give us a **[mcve]!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are replacing your quotes with spaces:

```
...
$u = str_replace("'", " ", $u );  
$u =  str_replace('"', ' ', $u );
...
```

So the string `O'reily` will be converted to `O reily`. Then it will not match because your regexp does not match spaces. Replace your `"\'"` with just `" "`:

```
if(preg_match("/[^a-z_\-0-9 ]/i", $u))
{
   echo "<b class='Usernametaken'>Please do not use any symbols</b>";
}
```

Just note that will work for both double and single quotes. Or you can simply remove the two lines that replaced quotes with spaces, and your original regexp will work.